# Abp Template Problem for MVC Core - JQuery 4.6.0

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Using the very latest stable mvc core jquery template (4.6.0).

downloaded, ran db migration all good.

logged in using admin/123qwe and put a break point on the line AccountController line 104:

```
var loginResult = await GetLoginResultAsync(loginModel.UsernameOrEmailAddress, loginModel.Password, GetTenancyNameOrNull());
```

I'm seeing `success` result returned from above line.

**Problem**: The page stays on the login page (as though it was not authenticated) and I cannot navigate away to another page (eg `\About`)

No changes were made to the template code - What am I missing or should I report a bug in the repo?

Comment: Can you share if there is any error in the browser console?

Comment: checked - no errors

Comment: If there is no error, can you share the response header and body of the login http request

Comment: very odd.  I ran the same but this time I changed my browser to FireFox and it worked no problem.  I will uninstall/reinstall a fresh Chrome and see if that does the trick.

Comment: still no luck with Chrome post reinstall.  Edge, FireFox & Explorer all work.  It's obviously my environment

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to possibly be a local browser issue with a Chrome install.

To Fix the following steps were taken:

1) reinstall Chrome

2) clear all browser cookies, cache, history

3) restart Chrome, Close Chrome

4) re-run Abp app using Chrome